# Are there any way to tell if comparison between C constant pointers are made in GCC and Clang without manual static analysis?

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, clang, comparison

This is to see what lines of code are affected by -fmerge-all-constants.

For example:

```
// main.c

#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int foo(const int* p){
    const int c[2] = {68,41};
    assert(p != c);
    if(!p)
        return foo(c);
    puts("DONE");
    return 0;
}

int main(void){
    foo(NULL);
}
```

It should include the filename, line, and line’s content. This example would show like main.c:8 and the line `assert(p != c);`.
If a macro function is used, like `#define min(X, Y)  ((X) < (Y) ? (X) : (Y))`, it should tell that this macro does constant pointer comparison with line number and filename.

I tried searching in internet but can’t find it.

Comment: This sure seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  What actual **problem** would such a tool be used to solve?

Comment: I don't even understand what you're asking.  Are you looking for a compiler option to cause it to notify about (some) pointer comparisons?  Or do you want to write a macro that performs your test?  Or something else? And what is significant to you about "constant pointers" (by which you seem to mean pointers to `const` types), as opposed to other pointers?

Comment: @AndrewHenle To see which part of the code that -fmerge-all-constants.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes if it helps. I do not want to write any code or macros.

Comment: I'm not following how you think detecting comparisons of any kind will help you determine which constants or variables might be merged when `-fmerge-all-constants` is in effect.  Note, moreover, that the `const` qualifier is pretty much unrelated to "constants" in the sense of `-fmerge-all-constants`.  And it's unclear why you're even interested.

Answer (score 0):

The pointer parameter `p`, and the local array `c`, cannot, by the language definition, have the same address, so they always compare as not equal.

Local array `c` must have an address (if it is used) which is distinct from other variables, including other instances of `c` in other recursion levels of `foo()`, and pointer parameter `p` cannot have been *passed in* as the local variable `c` at the *current* recursion level, so `p` can never equal `c`. This is irrespective of the `-fmerge-all-constants` option.

If I compile the following code:

```
int foo(const int* p) {
    const int c[2] = {68,41};
    return p != c;
}
```

with `gcc -O2 -S -masm=intel`, I get something like this on x86 (truncated for brevity):

```
foo:
        mov     eax, 1
        ret
```

The compiler is able to infer that `p != c` is always true, so it returns 1 (`true`) always, without testing the pointers at runtime. Since `c` is not used except in a comparison which can be eliminated, `c` can be eliminated as well.

I take it from your question, that you are asking how to tell whether the compiler is comparing the `p` and `c` addresses. This is best done by looking at the generated assembly code, which, as shown above, eliminates the comparisons at `-O2`.

The `-fmerge-all-constants` option is unsafe, since it may merge constant local arrays at different recursion levels, which, even if they are initialized identically, must have distinct addresses if those addresses are used, such as by passing them to another function call, or comparing them to other addresses.

However, the compiler is free to optimize away the pointer comparison, regardless of whether it merges the constant arrays at all levels, since the pointer comparison can be separately optimized away within the rules of the language, and has no effect or dependency on whether the arrays end up being merged or not.

By comparing the address of `c` with `p`, you are implicitly agreeing that `c` will have a unique address for the purposes of comparison, whether or not it actually ends up being unique.

From the documentation:

`-fmerge-all-constants`

> Attempt to merge identical constants and identical variables.
>
> This option implies `-fmerge-constants`. In addition to
> `-fmerge-constants` this considers e.g. even constant initialized
> arrays or initialized constant variables with integral or
> floating-point types. Languages like C or C++ require each variable,
> including multiple instances of the same variable in recursive calls,
> to have distinct locations, so using this option results in
> non-conforming behavior.

The safer `-fmerge-constants` does not merge a constant variable whose address is used, or a constant local variable in a recursive function.